# Order of destruction for static function members in shared libraries

Tags: c++, destructor, static-variables

I'm currently exploring a very tricky bug in Boost.Serialization related to singletons. For context: Boost 1.65 changed the implementation of the singleton breaking the `is_destructed` notification which leads to segfaults on program exit or library unload. Boost 1.66 "fixed" this but leaks memory.

The singleton code (relevant to this question) boils down to this:

```
template<class T> struct singleton{
    T& inst(){
        static T t;
        return t;
    }
}
```

Using a static member function variable avoids the [static init fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#construct-on-first-use-v2) but still has the same problem with destruction.

However [Finding C++ static initialization order problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335369/finding-c-static-initialization-order-problems#335746) shows code how to solve that: When the Ctor of `A` uses `B` then `B` will be constructed first and hence destructed last. This is also stated in [Destruction order of static objects in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469597/destruction-order-of-static-objects-in-c/469613#469613). (`completion of the destructor happens in the reverse order of the completion of the constructor`)

So far so good. Boost.Serialization now uses multiple singletons of type `extended_type_info_typeid<T>` to register some meta-data of the usertype `T` in another singleton `std::multiset<const bs::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0*,...>`. This is done by using the `multiset` (assume all singletons from here) from the constructor of `extended_type_info_typeid_0`. In the destructor of `extended_type_info_typeid_0` the entry in the `multiset` is removed.

This means we have exactly the situation described above and the `multiset` should outlive the other instances.

This breaks down when using shared libraries. I have the following test case:

```
test_multi_singleton.cpp:

int f();
int g();

int main(int argc, char**){
  // Make sure symbols are used
  if(argc==8) return f();
  if(argc==9) return g();
}

multi_singleton1.cpp:
#include <boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp>

int f(){
  return 0 != boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<int>::get_const_instance().get_key();
} 

multi_singleton2.cpp:
#include <boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp>

int g(){
  // Use different(!) type
  return 0 != boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<float>::get_const_instance().get_key();
} 

Build with:

g++ multi_singleton1.cpp -lboost_serialization -fPIC -shared -olibmulti_singleton1.so
g++ multi_singleton2.cpp -lboost_serialization -fPIC -shared -olibmulti_singleton2.so
g++ test_multi_singleton.cpp -L. -lmulti_singleton1 -lmulti_singleton2

Run in valgrind:
valgrind ./a.out
```

One can see that this corrupts memory in Boost 1.65. The reason is the messed up order which I traced by hijacking and logging the ctor/dtor calls:

```
ctor 0x7f9f0aa074a0 std::multiset<const extended_type_info_typeid_0*>
ctor 0x7f9f0a7f63e0 extended_type_info_typeid<float>

ctor 0x7f9f0a7f64a0 std::multiset<const extended_type_info_typeid_0*>
ctor 0x7f9f0aa073e0 extended_type_info_typeid<int>

dtor 0x7f9f0aa073e0 extended_type_info_typeid<int>
dtor 0x7f9f0aa074a0 std::multiset<const extended_type_info_typeid_0*>
dtor 0x7f9f0a7f64a0 std::multiset<const extended_type_info_typeid_0*>
dtor 0x7f9f0a7f63e0 extended_type_info_typeid<float>
```

This is using GCC 6.4, but same with GCC 7.1. As you can see the 2 multisets are destroyed together and before the 2nd `extended_type_info_typeid`.

Am I missing anything? Is this allowed by the C++ standard?

Comment: Solution to this (and many other related problems): *Don't* use singletons. They are an *anti*-pattern and tend to cause many more problems than they solve.

Comment: The standard doesn't say anything about dynamic load libraries.

Answer (score 1):

From [basic.start.term/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.term#3):

> If the completion of the constructor or dynamic initialization of an
>   object with static storage duration strongly happens before that of
>   another, the completion of the destructor of the second is sequenced
>   before the initiation of the destructor of the first.

Also:

> For an object of array or class type, all subobjects of that object are
>   destroyed **before** any block-scope object with static storage duration
>   initialized during the construction of the subobjects is destroyed.

Comment: How does this help? The 2nd map should not be destroyed before the 2nd type_info.