# c++ understanding accessing global variables after cleanup does not give some sort of error

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, runtime-error, global-variables

I have a question about how global variables work in c++.
**I know global variables are evil so that is not the point of this question. I just want a deeper understanding of what is happening in the following example.**

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class B
{
public:
  B();
  ~B();
private:
  static std::vector<int32_t> v_;
};

B::B()
{
  std::cout << "v_.size() = " << v_.size() << std::endl;
  for (auto i : v_)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

B::~B()
{
  std::cout << "v_.size() = " << v_.size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "v_[0] = " << v_[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "v_.at(0) = " << v_.at(0) << std::endl;
  for (auto i : v_)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

B b;

std::vector<int32_t> B::v_ { 5, -7 };

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Gives this output:

```
$ ./test 
v_.size() = 0
v_.size() = 2
v_[0] = 0
v_.at(0) = 0
0
0
```

Why is the size of the vector in the destructor of B still 2?

When I access the elements of the vector I get random memory, which I sort of understand because the vector gets cleaned up before B. But to me the size of the vector should be 0 or even way better throw some sort of error when asking for the size. Even when using at() function It doesn't throw an error because the size is still 2.

I also know I can fix this by switching the initialization of b and the vector. My question is more why this specific example doesn't throw some sort of error, cause in my opinion it should.

Note: like my comment:  why does this behavior fall under undefined behavior instead of reading or writing an illegal memory location since the vector doesn't exist at that point? I was kinda thinking this would/should generate a seg fault and I don't understand why it doesn't

Comment: "_My question is more why this specific example doesn't throw some sort of error, cause in my opinion it should._" Why should it throw any error? Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destruction order of static objects in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469597/destruction-order-of-static-objects-in-c)

Comment: The vector doesn't exist at that point. There is nothing it *can* do.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior in `B::B` already, by way of accessing `B::v_` before its lifetime has started.

Comment: mhh so this falls under undefined behavior instead of reading or writing an illegal memory location since the vector doesn't exist at that point? I was kinda thinking this would/should generate a seg fault and I don't understand why it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined behavior means that the behavior of your program is not defined by the C++ standard.  A conforming C++ compiler can do **anything** with a program that has, or **will**, exhibit undefined behavior (yes, UB can time travel).

Your program exhibits undefined behavior by accessing `v_` as an object prior to it being constructed in `B::B`.  Given that it does this, nothing about your programs execution is specified or constrained by the C++ standard.

In this case, the compiler treats the UB access as if it was accessing an empty `std::vector`.  This is valid, because **anything is valid**.  The program then proceeds as-if you hadn't done the UB (other than the above symptom), which is also a valid option.

If we imagine removing the UB in the ctor, during destruction your program again exhibits UB.  This time by accessing `v_` as a `vector` object after it was destroyed.  Again, by doing this the behavior of your program is not defined or constrained by the C++ standard, before, at, and after the UB.

In this case, it behaves as if you have a vector of 2 values whose values are 0.  That is conforming, because **anything is conforming**.

One of many possibilities is that the data was recycled on the heap, but the pointers where left dangling.  Treating the vector's "rotted" data as pointers they still point 2 `sizeof(int)` apart, and `.size()` reads that as 2.  The data pointed to, however, has been recycled on the heap, and there is different data there.