# How some objects are created before main event loop?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qeventloop

While debugging, I came up with strange for me thing. In the main function, I commented out creation of window as follows:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QDebug>

//#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << "Creating QApplication";
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "QAplication has been created successfully";

    qDebug() << "Creating application window";
    // MainWindow w;
    qDebug() << "Displaying application window";
    // w.show();
    qDebug() << "Application window has been displayed successfully";

    return a.exec();
}
```

I thought I am just creating an event loop and lunching it. But output surprised me:

```
"17:28:32.793" ButtonControl: contructor.
"17:28:32.807" GestureControl: contructor
Creating QApplication
QAplication has been created successfully
Creating application window
Displaying application window
Application window has been displayed successfully
```

I have `ButtonControl` and `GestureControl` classes and first 2 lines of output are from their constructors. I create their objects inside of other class, which I use in MainWindow class. The strange thing for me is they are created before/without MainWindow and event loop. Their messages are printed even if I don't create `QApplication` object and call its `exec()` method. I tried **clean**ing and **run**ning **qmake**, and **rebuild**ing, but no success. What's going on here? What is wrong with `ButtonControl` and `GestureControl` classes?

Env: win7, Qt 5.10, MSVC 2015.

---

### Edit

Here is my `Control` class:

```
class Control : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Control(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    static ButtonControl *getButtonController() {
        return &buttonController;
    }
    static GestureControl *getGestureController() {
        return &gestureController;
    }

private:
    static ButtonControl buttonController;
    static GestureControl gestureController;
};
```

I call this class inside my MainWindow. (As I understand from comments this code snippet is enough)

Comment: Maybe some static instances inside QT?

Comment: Without seeing the code for your classes, how would we know? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, they are static classes inside of `Control` class. BUT I don't create `Control` objects either.

Comment: Static class instances are automatically created during dynamic initialization stage which typically happens before `main` starts.

Comment: Just set a break point inside `ButtonControl: contructor`, inspect the stack trace.

Comment: @nvoigt I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following comments, I did a small research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10464060/6407320) answer:

> Static members are initialized before main(), and they are destroyed in reverse order of creation after the return in main().
>
> Static members are statically allocated, and their lifetime begins and ends with the program.

Thank you everyone who commented out.