# Static object's constructor not being called

Tags: c++

I have a header file which defines two objects:

```
// header.h
static A object1("param1", "param2");
static A object2("param1", "param2");
```

This is how A looks like:

```
class A {
    public:
    int random;
    A(char* p1, char* p2){
        printf("Called constructor for %s | %s\n", p1, p2);
    }
};
```

However, the constructor is never getting called. I'm doing this:

```
#include "header.h"

int main(){
    // to prevent optimization issues
    object1.random = rand();
    if (object1.random != 3) { printf("\n"); }
    return 0;
}
```

And I never see the messages on the console, it just remains empty.

I've read about the `static initialization order fiasco`, but I believe it's not the problem here, because neither of those objects is relying on the other one, so order doesn't really matter...

I'm using MSVC++ 2013 on Windows 7 x64

Comment: The code is not perfect -- you should use `A(char const* p1, char const* p2) {` -- but it should work.

Comment: Which compiler/version are you using, and with what compile flags?

Comment: It may have something to do with optimization. Try referencing `object1` and `object2` in `main`.

Comment: Can you add a little more details about your environment? Compiler, version, OS etc.

Comment: Please use breakpoint to watch console, if you use Win7 and Visual Studio, it should be OK.

Comment: @rici and MohitJain: Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2013. Lingxi: tried, doesn't change anything. thinkerou I did add a breakpoint, but it doesn't ever hit.

Comment: Are they inside a class or just floating around? In the latter case, you will have a copy of them for every source file.

Comment: Do you see the blank line from `printf("\n");` being printed?

Comment: @MikeDeSimone yes, I do. NeilKirk: they're just 'floating around', yes. Does that change the fact that they need to be constructed before used?

Answer (score 0):

[When are static C++ class members initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421671/when-are-static-c-class-members-initialized) contains a great answer about this topic.

In short there are 3 guarantees (citing the original [Tadeusz Kopec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113662/tadeusz-kopec) answer in the above mentioned question):

1. Objects defined in the same translation unit (usually it means .cpp file) are initialized in order of their definitions
2. Initialization of static objects from a translation unit will be done before use of any object or function from this translation unit
3. They will be initialized before main is entered.

If in your specific case static variables `object1` and `object2` were not initialized this could be related to a compiler optimization omitting the initialization of unused variables. You can verify this easily by adding a usage of these variables inside main and observe whether these got initialized and when.

Comment: check the edit -- I added code to avoid optimizations (and I'm compiling in `Debug` mode with disabled optimizations), and still it doesn't get called.

Comment: Besides, these aren't static class members, they're static objects, which means they lack external linkage.