# Why is the constructor of a static member called before the constructor of the containing class?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A() { cout << "A's constructor called " << endl;  }
};

class B
{
    static A a;
public:
    B() { cout << "B's constructor called " << endl; }
    static A getA() { return a; }
};

A B::a;  // definition of a

int main()
{
    B b1, b2, b3;
    A a = b1.getA();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
A's constructor called
B's constructor called
B's constructor called
B's constructor called

I am not able to understand how we got the above output and how object declared of 1st class in class 2nd.

Comment: Why do you think the output is wrong?

Comment: The `static` declaration of `A` in class `B` causes the first constructor called.  The compiler will emit code to initialize global and *static* variables before `main` is called.

Comment: If you step through your code with the debugger, it should become pretty clear why it's behaving like this. `static A a;` is a static object and will be instantiated once for all instances of `B`.

Comment: Look at the generated assembly code and verify that the compiler emitted code for the assignment statement in `main`.  Since the `a` variable is not used in `main`, the compiler may not have generated any code that constructs an instance of `A`. (Or it may have generated the code, then removed the code during optimization.)

Comment: ok got the concept. thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not able to understand how we got the above output and how object declared of 1st class in class 2nd.

```
static A a;
```

is a static member of `class B` and will be instantiated once for all instances of `B`.

This happens even before `main()` is entered, and you're lucky that

```
cout << "A's constructor called " << endl;
```

worked well, since `static` instances aren't guaranteed to be initialized in a specific order (note that `std::cout` is just another `static` object instance).

Comment: "`static` instances aren't guaranteed to be initialized in a specific order" -- That's not quite right, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421671/when-are-static-c-class-members-initialized), but I understand the spirit of your statement. "objects defined in the same translation unit (usually it means .cpp file) are initialized in order of their definitions (not declarations)"