# c++ static unorderd_map used in static method is not initialized

Tags: c++, stl

I have some code where a static method is called, and the static `std::unordered_map` within the same file is not initialized. I understand the static initialization between two compile units is "undefined" and there are many `SO` questions on the topic; however, when I use an `std::vector` the issue does not occur. Also, the code *can* execute, but I am confused as to why *these specific compile orders* do not work. `SO`, my questions are:

1. There is another `SO` question (which I've been unable to find!) about static initialization and dynamic initialization of static variables. Is this error due to `std::undored_map` actually being a dynamic initialization?
2. is there a way to get this code to initialize the `std::unordered_map` as I expected? I'm actually trying to create a static library `.lib` or `.a`. When I link the static library, it generally needs to come last, and so the error occurs.
3. are there any workarounds for this? One option I've thought of is to create both an `std::vector` and an `std::unordered_map`. Use the `std::vector` while the `std::unordered_map` is uninitialized (via `bool _map_is_initialized`). Change the initialization of the `std::unordered_map` to be explicitly dynamic by calling a function which iterates over the values in the `std::vector` to produce the `std::unordered_map`.

**Linux**

```
g++ -std=c++1y -g -c thing.cpp
g++ -std=c++1y -g -c main.cpp
g++ -g main.o thing.o -o main
./main
```

This results in a `Floating point exception (core dumped)` error. Through `gdb`, I was able to figure out that `hashtable_policy.h` trys `__num % __den;` where `__den==0`. Also using `gdb`, it appears as though `Thing::Things` is uninitialized.

```
(gdb) break thing.cpp:12
(gdb) run
(gdb) print Thing::Things
No symbol "Things" in specified context.
(gdb) print thing
$1 = (Thing *) 0x618c20
```

**Windows**

```
cl /EHsc /Zi /c main.cpp
cl /EHsc /Zi /c thing.cpp
link /debug main.obj thing.obj
main
```

In my actual code, this resulted in a very clear segmentation fault; however, this example just opens a popup that says the application failed. ... I have not done better diagnostics.

**Code**

> `thing.cpp`
>
> ```
> #include<iostream>
>
> #include "thing.hpp"
>
> std::vector<Thing*> Before; // EDIT: added
>
> std::unordered_map<std::string, Thing*> Thing::Things;
>
> std::vector<Thing*> After;  // EDIT: added
>
> Thing::Thing(std::string name) : name(name) {
>
> }
>
> bool Thing::Register(Thing *thing) {
>     std::cout << "no worries, vectors initialized..." << std::endl;
>     Thing::Before.push_back(thing); // EDIT: added
>     Thing::After.push_back(thing);  // EDIT: added
>     std::cout << "added to vectors, about to fail..." << std::endl;
>     Thing::Things[thing->name] = thing;
>     return true;
> }
> ```
>
> `thing.hpp`
>
> ```
> #pragma once
> #include <string>
> #include <unordered_map>
>
> class Thing {
> public:
>     static std::vector<Thing*> Before; // EDIT: added
>
>     static std::unordered_map<std::string, Thing*> Things;
>
>     static std::vector<Thing*> After; // EDIT: added
>
>     static bool Register(Thing* thing);
>
>     std::string name;
>
>     Thing(std::string name);
> };
>
> #define ADD_THING(thing_name) \
>     static bool thing_name## _is_defined = Thing::Register(new Thing( #thing_name ));
> ```
>
> `main.cpp`
>
> ```
> #include "thing.hpp"
> #include <iostream>
>
> ADD_THING(obligatory);
> ADD_THING(foo);
> ADD_THING(bar);
>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
>     std::cout << "before loop" << std::endl;
>     for (auto thing : Thing::Things) {
>         std::cout << "thing.name: " << thing.first << std::endl;
>     }
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

**EDIT**

If the order within a given compile unit is guaranteed, why do `static std::vector<Thing*> Thing::Before` and `static std::vector<Thing*> Thing::After` get initialized, but `static std::unordered_map<std::string, Thing*> Thing::Things` does not?

Comment: see this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/211237/335858

Comment: Can you move the ADD_THING macros to within main()?  Or some other function called from main()?

Comment: @Nim, it is not clear to me how the *static initialization order fiasco* is an issue given that `Thing::Things` has no method being used to initialize it.

Comment: @SimplyKnownAsG For your code to work, the default `std::unordered_map` constructor for `Thing::Things` (statically invoked) must be called *before* the initialization of `thing_name## _is_defined` (which statically invokes `Thing::Register` via the `ADD_THING` macros).  That order is not guaranteed, hence the static initialization order problem.

Comment: @nephtes, that makes sense. I've edited with another question though. Basically, it appears as though *some* static variables do initialize, just not the `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @SimplyKnownAsG What leads you to believe that "the order within a given compile unit is guaranteed"?

Comment: @nephtes, I've read it in other `SO` questions, [such as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211237/static-variables-initialisation-order), and although [this is gcc specific](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html) it talks about a *translation unit*... I've never delved into the standard myself, and am relatively new to C++

Comment: @SimplyKnownAsG ah, interesting.  Wasn't aware of that.  Well, I tried your edited example, and although I had to fix some compiler/linker errors (added `#include <vector>` to `thing.hpp` and changed `std::vector<Thing*> Before` to `std::vector<Thing*> Thing::Before` in `thing.cpp`; likewise `After`), it works (g++ 4.9.2).  This is strictly luck, of course, since there's still no guarantee about the order of `ADD_THING` vs `Thing::Things`, but I wasn't able to reproduce out-of-order initialization within a single .cpp file.  What toolchain had you built with when that happened?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124580/discussion-between-simplyknownasg-and-nephtes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static initialization is tricky.  As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421780/810632) states, the standard provides some guarantees as to the order of initialization within a single "translation unit" (normally a .cpp source file), but none whatsoever concerning what order initializations in different translation units will follow.

When you added the `Before` and `After` vectors to the code, you observed that unlike the calls to `ordered_map::operator[]`, the calls to `vector::push_back()` did not crash the process and concluded that the objects were being initialized out of order within a single translation unit, contrary to the standard's guarantees.  There is a hidden assumption there, namely that since `push_back()` did not cause a crash, the vector must therefore have been initialized.  This turns out not to be the case: that method call on an uninitialized object is almost certainly corrupting memory somewhere, but won't necessarily cause a crash.  A better way of checking whether or not the constructor is being called would be to run the code in a debugger, and set breakpoints on the lines which contain the objects' definitions, for instance `std::vector<Thing*> Before` in `thing.cpp`.  This will show that initialization will occur as predicted in the standard.

The best option for avoiding the "fiasco", as described [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use), is "construct on first use".  In the case of your example code, this would involve changing any direct use of `Thing::Things`, such as this line:

```
Thing::Things[thing->name] = thing;
```

To a method, say `Thing::GetThings()`, which initializes the object and returns a reference to it.  [lcs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39772686/810632) provides an example of this, but beware: although it solves the static initialization problem, using a scoped static object may introduce an even more pernicious problem: crashes on program exit due to [static deinitialization order](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#construct-on-first-use-v2).  For that reason, allocating the object with the `new` keyword is preferred:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Thing*>& Thing::GetThings()
{
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, Thing*>* pThings =
        new std::unordered_map<std::string, Thing*>();
    return *pThings;
}
```

That instance will of course never be `delete`'d, which feels an awful lot like a memory leak.  But even if it weren't a pointer, de-initialization would only occur at program shutdown. So, unless the object's destructor performs some important function like flushing a file's contents to disk, the only difference that matters is the fact that using a pointer avoids the possibility of a crash on exit.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, static initialization order is not defined. Who knows the difference between vector and map. Maybe your compiler initializes classes with even number of characters in their name first.

If you're running `c++11` or greater, static initialization of function local items is guaranteed to be thread safe. They will be initialized the first time control passes through the declaration statement.

```
// Header
class Thing {
public:
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, Thing*>& Things();
    static bool Register(Thing* thing);


// CPP
std::unordered_map<std::string, Thing*>& Thing::Things()
{
   static std::unordered_map<std::string, Thing*> things;
   return things;
}
```

This will initialize the first time you ask for the `Things`, and avoids all the potential randomness of static initialization.