# Why is static member of a template initialized after an object defined later in the same translation unit?

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

Consider the following (artificial) example:

```
#include <iostream>

int f() {
  return 42;
}

template <typename T>
struct S {
  static int I;
};

template <typename T>
int S<T>::I = f();

template <typename T>
int g() {
  return S<T>::I;
}

int global = g<int>();

int main() {
  std::cout << global << std::endl;
}
```

It prints 0 when compiled with gcc 4.8.4 and run:

```
$ g++ test.cc
$ ./a.out
0
```

This suggests that dynamic initialization for `global` is run before the initialization for `S<T>::I>`. However, according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421780/471164),

> objects defined in the same translation unit (usually it means .cpp file) are initialized in order of their definitions

Why is dynamic initialization for `global` run before the one for `S<T>::I>` and not in the order of their definitions and is it possible to force `global` be initialized after?

Comment: [clang gives 42](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/169879aab97b4357) (and VS2015 gives 0)

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#1

Comment: I wonder if there is any trick to force the desired initialization here.

Comment: "Why is dynamic initialization for global run before the one for S<T>::I> and not in the order of their definitions" because `template <typename T>int S<T>::I = f();` is not a definition, it is defined when you instantiate it, when you call `g<int>()` and that's after `global` defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [initialization of `S<T>::I` is unordered](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#1), the value for `S<int>::I` can be either 0 (if it is initialized after `global`) or 42 (if initialized before `global`).

While you can't force the compiler to initialize `I` before `global`, with a slight change in your code you can employ the same method used to order static variables defined in different translation units.  By changing `I` to a function that stores its value in an internal static variable, you can ensure that it is initialized before `global`.

```
template <typename T>
struct S {
  static int I() {
    static int i = f();
    return i;
  }
};

template <typename T>
int g() {
  return S<T>::I();
}
```