# access to optionally present members of base template class

Tags: c++, templates, preprocessor

Suppose I have a template class, which depending on a template parameter, may or may not have a member `int x`.
This can be realized by inheriting from a base template class, which for some specialization has a member `int x`.

Example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <bool present>
struct base;

template <>
struct base<true> { int x; };

template <bool present>
struct base { };

template <bool activate>
struct A : public base<activate> {
    void print() const;
};

template <bool activate>
void A<activate>::print() const
{
    if constexpr (activate) {
        std::cout << "x = " << this->x << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "nothing" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    A<true> a;
    a.print();
    A<false> b;
    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

In the code above `A<true>` contains a member `int x`, inherited from `base<true>`, whereas `A<false>` does not contain it.

Now, since `x` is a dependent name, in order to access it, I need to use `this->x` or `base<true>::x`. This can be somewhat burdersome to use it every time, so the common solution is to employ a `using` directive like

```
using base<true>::x;
```

inside the definition of `A`. But, of course, this makes sense only when `activate=true`.

Is it possible, perhaps with a macro, to add `using base<true>::x` in the definition of `A`, only when a condition (here `activate=true`) is satisfied?

Comment: What compiler are you using? What version? I ask because this is trivial with concepts and template meta-programming but requires a new-ish compiler that supports at least late features of C++20 or early previews of C++23.

Comment: Hacking by adding dummy `typedef` ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o4dPcqrnj)) or static var ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z4oTd98Ge)) seems to pass with gcc/msvc, but not with clang.

Comment: @Casey I use the c++17 standard, although the compilers I am typically using (g++ >=11), should partially support c++20 I think.

Comment: @Jarod42 your second option (with a ```static struct dummy``` member) seems to work with all compilers, including clang.

Comment: Indeed, I got a "refresh" issue on clang with static var. but passes indeed with all compiler.

Comment: @Jarod42 Concerning the solution with a ```static struct dummy```. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421780/8769985) I get that whether the code compiles or not is implementation-dependent: the initialization of the incomplete type ```static dummy x``` *can* be deferred before its first use (in which case if I don't use it at all, it is never initialized), but it could also be initialized before main (in which case the code would not compile). Is that right? Anyway it works with all compilers I may use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another placeholder option is use a function, with the benefit that one can `delete` it to prevent unwanted access.

```cpp
template <bool present>
struct base { constexpr void x()=delete; };

template <>
struct base<true> { int x = 0; };

template <bool activate>
struct A : public base<activate> {
    using base<activate>::x;
    void print() const{
        auto&& p = x; // fail for A<false>::print
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a common issue to have optionally present members. If you're okay with multiple inheritance and some hacking, you can do this via a `static` empty variable in another base class:

```
struct Nothing {};

struct StaticNothing {
    static Nothing x;   
};

template <bool activate>
struct A : public base<activate>, StaticNothing {
    using std::conditional_t<activate, base<true>, StaticNothing>::x;
    void print() const;
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/1PDKQ5xbD)

Note that `std::conditional_t<>` decides which base `x` comes from. The benefit of this method is, you can always assume that there's an `x` member (either static or non-static), so you can take the address of it, etc.

Comment: imo [the option provide by @Jarod42 in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74998170/access-to-optionally-present-members-of-base-template-class/74998451#comment132349643_74998170) is better, the name is always presented in `base<x>`, just defined differently https://godbolt.org/z/GKnGo6e98

Comment: @appleapple You can use that - as long as you can use that. Sometimes `base<>` is in a library / code part where you are not allowed to modify anything. `A` is assumed to be under implementation, therefore, by definition, modifiable (and `Nothing` / `StaticNothing` can reside anywhere).

Comment: @Iorro well there can always be another layer.

Answer (score 1):

base on the comment of [@Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74998170/access-to-optionally-present-members-of-base-template-class?noredirect=1#comment132349643_74998170), but use anonymous class (optional) and inline variable to make sure it compiles without extra definitions. (regarding to [OP's this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74998170/access-to-optionally-present-members-of-base-template-class/75003647#comment132357811_74998170))

```cpp
template <bool present>
struct base { constexpr static struct{} x = {}; };
template <>
struct base<true> { int x = 0; };

template <bool activate>
struct A : public base<activate> {
    using base<activate>::x;
    void print() const;
};
```