# Is the behaviour is determined when initliasing the inner class's static member variable's value equal to the outer class's static member variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the output is determined? Here is the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/hb9ez5hhM):

```
#include <iostream>

class Outer {
public:
    class Inner {
    public:
        Inner() {}
        void func(Outer& outer) ;
        static const int thrd;
    };

private:
    static const int num;
    int var;
};

void Outer::Inner::func(Outer& outer) {
    outer.var = 1;
}


const int Outer::Inner::thrd = Outer::num;
const int Outer::num = 5;

int main(){

    std::cout << "Outer::Inner::thrd=" << Outer::Inner::thrd << std::endl; //is the output is determined?
}
```

Comment: You assing Outer:: num to Outer::Inner::thrd before Outer::num it is initalized. Initialization of statics is done in the order you initialize them in source (not by the order in which they are declared). However if possible do not write code like this (with global statics).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421780/12002570) in the dupe [When are static C++ class members initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421671/when-are-static-c-class-members-initialized). Also see [Static variables initialisation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211237/static-variables-initialisation-order)

Comment: Minor point about terminology. Java has "inner" and "outer" classes with some magical relationship between them. C++ does not.  Usually the term is "class" and "nested class". Not that "inner" and "outer" are in any way wrong, just sometimes confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid static (global) variables. You might run into the [static initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) at some point when you want to do this kind of things across multiple translation units.

So use `constexpr` whenever you can. That way you cannot initialize constants the wrong way. (in header files replace static constexpr, with inline constexpr)

```
#include <iostream>

class Outer 
{
private:
    static constexpr int num{5};

public:
    class Inner {
    public:
        Inner() {}
        void func(Outer& outer) ;
        static constexpr int thrd{num};
    };

private:
    int var;
};

void Outer::Inner::func(Outer& outer) 
{
    outer.var = 1;
}

int main(){

    std::cout << "Outer::Inner::thrd=" << Outer::Inner::thrd << std::endl; //is the output is determined?
}
```

Comment: Is it suitable to use with C++11?

Comment: constexpr has been added in C++11 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr. Is there a reason you're limited to C++11. I mean that version is literally over a decade old ;)