# Global const initializing and difference between constructor in .h or .cpp file

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

I was wondering why sometimes my global const defined in seperate .h file isn't properly initialized when I need it. Some tests lead me to situation that I can't understand. I don't know how to explain it, so here's the code:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"
using namespace std;

A a;
B b;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
A aa;
B bb;
cout<<a.a<<" "<<aa.a<<endl;
cout<<b.b<<" "<<bb.b<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

#### class.h

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H
#include "const.h"

class A {
public:
A();
float a;
};

class B {
public:
B():b(CONST){}
float b;
};
#endif
```

#### class.cpp

```
#include "class.h"
A::A()
: a(CONST){}
```

#### const.h

```
#ifndef CONST_H
#define CONST_H
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

const float CONST = numeric_limits<float>::has_infinity ? 
        -numeric_limits<float>::infinity() : 
        -numeric_limits<float>::max();
#endif
```

After running above code I get:

> 0 -1.#INF
>   -1.#INF -1.#INF

when actually I would like to get 4 times '-1.#INF'.
Why does it happen this way? If CONST would be '1' instead of above formula, it would work perfectly.

I can "fix" it by making static getConst() method:

```
static float getConst(){
static const float CONST = numeric_limits<float>::has_infinity ? 
        -numeric_limits<float>::infinity() : 
        -numeric_limits<float>::max();
return CONST;}
```

but it just doesn't "feel" right. On other hand I just need two of those above... But maybe there's some other way?

And, most importantly, why class B gets "right" CONST and class A don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant objects have internal linkage, so you get a separate copy of `CONST` in each compilation unit that includes `const.h`. In this case, you'll get one in `main.cpp`, and one in `class.cpp`. You also have your two global objects in `main.cpp`.

C++ does not define the order in which global objects in different compilation units are initialised. `A`s constructor is called from `main.cpp`, and needs the global constant from `class.cpp`, which may not yet be initialised. In your particular case, it hasn't been, so you get the incorrect value you saw. `B`s constructor is inline, so it uses the global constant from `main.cpp`, which has been initialised since it is defined earlier in the same compilation unit.

By making the constant a function-static object, it is now guaranteed to be initialised when that function is first called.

Comment: Wow, thanks for comprehensive answer. I hoped that the fact, that B was initialized properly and A not, was somehow caused by B's inline constructor, but it's just because main.cpp "got lucky", and class.cpp not. However, as I understand, there's no way that this const wouldn't be initialized before main fucntion starts running?

Comment: @Koger: B's correct behaviour is in fact guaranteed; within a single compilation unit, global objects are initialised in the order they are defined, and `CONST` is defined (in the header file) before `B`. And yes, they will all be initialised before `main` starts.

Comment: Isn't class.cpp single compilation unit as well? And it theoretically includes class.h and const.h the same way main.cpp does, so CONST is defined before A.

Answer (score 3):

The order of initialization of global object in different translation unit is not guarantee.

Please have a look at this stackoverflow question: [Static variables initialisation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211237/c-static-variables-initialisation-order)

Comment: Thanks, that explained a lot. Funny thing is, I believe that it should behave the same way all the time now, as I'm using the same compiler etc., but as I opened and recompiled this project seconds ago, it initializes CONST soon enough for A::a to initialize properly

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the contents of `const.h` anywhere so I can only guess what `CONST` is (a macro?).

That aside, in your code example, the member variable `A::a` is not initialized. Hence, it could have any value - it's uninitialized.

Comment: Looks like somebody edited my question to make it look more neat. Now const.h is more visible. And A::a is initialized in class.cpp file

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question properly then I believe the problem is because the order of initialisation of any global objects is not defined.