# Static initialization in linked library under Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, static, initialization

I have a configuration that has a library and a console application.  They are pretty barebones at the moment.  I am using Visual Studio 2010 and the library and console application are both statically linked to the Runtime.  The console application also links to the library.

In the library, I can add this code in a source file:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        printf("MyClass loaded\n");
    }
};

class MyClass2
{
public:
    static MyClass my_class;
};

MyClass MyClass2::my_class;
```

Now, my understanding is that my_class should be initialized at some point before main().  However, it never happens (as I do not get the printed message).

I can, however, get it to initialize using two different methods:

1. Put the code in the console application instead.  Doing that will invoke the printf() statement for certain.
2. Modify MyClass2 to include a static function that is called from a global variable in the library and use that global variable in main() in the console application.

Example for #2 above:

Library file:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        printf("MyClass loaded\n");
    }
};

class MyClass2
{
public:
    static MyClass my_class;
    static int Ping();
};

MyClass MyClass2::my_class;
int my_global = MyClass2::Ping();
```

Console application file:

```
extern int my_global;
int main()
{
    printif("%d", my_global);
}
```

Is Windows trying to help me by delay loading the linked in library's static variables??  Or is there some compiler setting I have set? This behavior was totally unexpected by me.

Comment: It may be that your class is initialized before `stdout` (on which `printf` relies) is initialized?

Comment: Also, you might want to read [this old SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/211307/440558). While it's not Windows specific it should still be enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: In the first case where you define `my_class` in the library project, do you also use `my_class` in the console application project? If not, the linker may decide not to include these in the final binary, because it thinks it's not required. Another question: the library file is a header or a cpp in the library project?

Comment: It appears I got my answer.  Thanks guys.

To answer the questions anyway:
Joachim: I ruled that out (sorry I didn't say) by using an exit(0) as well and a printf() in main still printed.  Thanks for the link.
Alexander: It was in CPP files.  I believe you're on the right track as James also pointed out in his answer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You do raise an interesting point.  The C++ standard sets certain requirements for the initialization of `std::cout` (which the example almost certainly meets), but it says nothing about the initialization of `stdout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the "library file" part of the final executable.  If it is an
object file in a statically linked library, it will only be part
of the final executable if it resolves an otherwise unresolved
external symbol.  (This is the definition of a library.)  If you
never use any symbol in the object file, it won't be part of
your executable, and it's as if the source file wasn't part of
the application.

If the library is dynamically loaded, the situation is slightly
different; a `.dll` is loaded as a unit (and not object file by
object file, so it's not really a library), but if there are no
unresolved symbols which would be resolved by loading the DLL,
it won't be loaded either.

What you probably want to do is link against the object files,
and *not* against a library.  In Visual Studios, this means
putting all of the sources in the same project.  Or... you can
link the library as a `.dll`, and then explicitly load it using
`LoadLibrary`.  (This is what we do for libraries which are only
referenced because they have constructors of static objects
which register themselves.)

Comment: Thanks much.  I considered that at one point and tried to even just "export" a random integer, and it didn't work.  However, I *may* have been a victim of PCH or similar, as I tried it again now and it worked (of course, header files have also been updated, so maybe that's it too).  Either way, this reply does make sense. Thanks!