# SIGSEGV with std::map of pointers to template objects

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, g++, stdmap

I need to keep a std::map of pointers to templated objects.
To get rid of templates, I use a common untemplated base class.

When running the code, I get a SIGSEGV signal. 
Debugging shows that the problem arises with statement

```
data_[id] = s;
```

It could be a problem related to the order of initialization of the objects.

The code looks like this:

*File shared_iface.h:*

```
class shared_iface {
    unsigned long int counter_;
};
```

*File shared.h:*

```
extern CommunicationHandler comm;

template <typename T>
class shared: private shared_iface {
public:
    shared(): data_(nullptr), id_(0) {
        comm.add(id_, this);
    }
private:
    T* data_;
    unsigned long int id_;
};
```

*File communication_handler.h:*

```
class CommunicationHandler {
public:
    inline void add(unsigned long int id, shared_iface* s) {
        data_.add(id, s);
    }
private:
    Dictionary data_;
};
```

*File communication_handler.cpp:*

```
CommunicationHandler comm;
```

*File dictionary.h:*

```
class Dictionary {
public:
    Dictionary() {
        data_.clear();
    }
    void add(unsigned long int id, shared_iface* s) {
        data_[id] = s;
    }
private:
    std::map<unsigned long int, shared_iface*> data_;
};
```

*File main.cpp:*

```
#include "shared.hpp"

shared<int> c;

int main ()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, naming the member of all your classes as `data_` is confusing. How about more descriptive names like `dictionary` and `interfaces`?

Comment: Initialization order of static objects across compilation units is indeed [undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/211237/4074081)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It could be a problem related to the order of initialization of the objects.

A good guess. `c` is a static object of type `shared<int>`. The constructor of`shared<T>` depends on the static object `comm`. `c` may very well be initialized before `comm` and you'll get undefined behaviour. `comm` could have been initialized first, you're lucky that your code didn't work.

This is known as [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order). The usual way to avoid the fiasco is [Construct On First Use Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use) but in general, avoid static objects that depend on other static objects.

Comment: Thank you so much. Don't know why but I couldn't see it. Now I've succesfully solved it by transforming CommunicationHandler into a Singleton.