# why is library loaded via LD_PRELOAD operating before initialization?

Tags: linux, ld-preload

In the following minimal example, a library loaded via `LD_PRELOAD` with functions to intercept `fopen` and `openat` is apparently operating before its initialization. (Linux is CentOS 7.3).  Why??

library file `comm.c`:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef FILE *(*fopen_type)(const char *, const char *);

// initialize to invalid value (non-NULL)
// init() should initialize this correctly
fopen_type g_orig_fopen = (fopen_type) 1;

typedef int (*openat_type)(int, const char *, int, ...);
openat_type g_orig_openat;

void init() {
    g_orig_fopen = (fopen_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"fopen");
    g_orig_openat = (openat_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"openat");
}

FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode) {
    // have to do this here because init is not called yet???
    FILE * const ret = ((fopen_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"fopen"))(filename, mode);

    printf("g_orig_fopen %p  fopen file %s\n", g_orig_fopen, filename);
    return ret;
}

int openat(int dirfd, const char* pathname, int flags, ...) {
    int fd;
    va_list ap;

    printf("g_orig_fopen %p  openat file %s\n", g_orig_fopen, pathname);

    if (flags & (O_CREAT)) {
        va_start(ap, flags);
        fd = g_orig_openat(dirfd, pathname, flags, va_arg(ap, mode_t));
    }
    else
        fd = g_orig_openat(dirfd, pathname, flags);

    return fd;
}
```

compiled with:

```
gcc -shared  -fPIC -Wl,-init,init  -ldl comm.c -o comm.so
```

I have an empty subdirectory `subdir`. Then it appears the library function `fopen` is called before `init`:

```
#LD_PRELOAD=./comm.so find subdir
g_orig_fopen 0x1  fopen file /proc/filesystems
g_orig_fopen 0x1  fopen file /proc/mounts
subdir
g_orig_fopen 0x7f7b2e574620  openat file subdir
```

Comment: It's hard to say what can cause this behavior, everything seems to be set correctly. I've read that with some `gcc` versions `init` named constructor function is not called -> try to change its name for example to `my_init`. Also try to add `-nostartfiles` to `gcc` options in order to prevent linking of standard `_init` function.

Comment: And as you probably know, with `gcc` you can use `__attribute__((constructor))` syntax to set constructor instead of linker `-init` option. It even allows to set many constructor functions that will be called successively. Use it!

void con() {
    printf("I'm a constructor\n");
}

Comment: @SergeyLebedev thank you Sergey, I really appreciate! No I did not know that `__attribute__`, I am a portable-type person.  I did try your suggestions, I did double-check they are implemented, but unfortunately, none of them seem to work, I still have the same erroneous printout as above. I am willing to accept the explanation that 'there is a bug' and 'here is a reasonable workaround'.

Comment: @SergeyLebedev It's always the temporary "files" in `/proc` directory that are opened before `my_init()`.  I am so sure someone with more Linux system experience than me can appreciate the significance of that.

Comment: @Mark. It may be that `selinux` library (mentioned in answer below) has higher constructor priority that yours. Refer to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211237/static-variables-initialisation-order

Comment: @ZbigniewZagórski I don't understand... when `selinux` runs for the first time during the run of `find`, with higher priority or whatever, then if it wants to call `fopen` then at that point the initialization function of `comm.so` should run, before `fopen`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, `fopen` is called before initialization of `comm.so`. It is interesting to place a breakpoint in `fopen()` in order to understand (check [this link](https://wiki.gnome.org/Community/GettingInTouch/Bugzilla/GettingTraces/DistroSpecificInstructions) in order to get debug symbols of various packages). I get this backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  fopen (filename=0x7ffff79cd2e7 "/proc/filesystems", mode=0x7ffff79cd159 "r") at comm.c:28
#1  0x00007ffff79bdb0e in selinuxfs_exists_internal () at init.c:64
#2  0x00007ffff79b5d98 in init_selinuxmnt () at init.c:99
#3  init_lib () at init.c:154
#4  0x00007ffff7de88aa in call_init (l=<optimized out>, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffdf58, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffdf68) at dl-init.c:72
#5  0x00007ffff7de89bb in call_init (env=0x7fffffffdf68, argv=0x7fffffffdf58, argc=1, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:30
#6  _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe170, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf58, env=0x7fffffffdf68) at dl-init.c:120
#7  0x00007ffff7dd9c5a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#8  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007fffffffe337 in ?? ()
#10 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

It is obvious, `comm.so` depends on other libraries (`libdl.so` that requires `libselinux.so`). And `comm.so` is not the only library that declare an init function. `libdl.so` and `libselinux.so` also declare ones.

So, `comm.so` is the first library to be loaded (because it is declared with `LD_PRELOAD`) but, `comm.so` depends on `libdl.so` (because of `-ldl` during compilation) and `libdl.so` depends on `libselinux.so`. So, in order to load `comm.so`, init functions from `libdl.so` and `libselinux.so` are called before. And finally, init function from `libselinux.so` call `fopen()`

Personally, I usually resolve dynamic symbols during first call to the symbol. Like this:

```c
FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode) {
    static FILE *(*real_fopen)(const char *filename, const char *mode) = NULL;

    if (!real_fopen)
        real_fopen = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");

    return real_fopen(filename, mode);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand... The documentation of the linker `-init` option says, this is the function that is executed when the executable is created. So, when I invoke find, the system starts to run it, at some point, somebody (`libselinux.so` for example), calls `fopen`, the first time that happens, before `fopen` actually runs, is that my `init` function should run.

Comment: also, please tell me, how do you "place a breakpoint in `fopen`" - you have the sources for standard library and recompile it with `-g` flag is that right?

Comment: `comm.so` is not the only library that declare an init function. `libdl.so` and `libselinux.so` also declare one. Because `comm.so` is declared with `LD_PRELOAD`, it is the first library to be loaded. BUT, `comm.so` depends on `libdl.so` (because of `-ldl` during compilation) and `libdl.so` depends on `libselinux.so`. So in order to load `comm.so`, init functions from `libdl.so` and `libselinux.so` are called.

Comment: In order to obtain a good backtrace, you need debug symbols. On most of distributions, debug symbols are delivered in separated packages. On Debian, [add debug repositories](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace#Installing_the_debugging_symbols), then install `libselinux1-dbgsym` and `libc6-amd64-dbgsym`

Comment: ... instructions for other distributions are described [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Community/GettingInTouch/Bugzilla/GettingTraces/DistroSpecificInstructions)

Comment: I am sorry to take so much of your time - yes I understand that they all have their init functions called, that was not my problem.  My problem is, when that other library has it's init function called, if that function calls `fopen` as that seems to be the case here, then, before `fopen` runs, my library has to be loaded, and when that happens, my `init` has to be called first.

Comment: `comm.so` depends on `libdl.so`. You can check that with `ldd comm.so`. So, `libdl.so` has to be initialized before `comm.so`. So, your library is not the first one to initialize.

Comment: OK but... When another library (the one to initialize before mine) initializes and wants to call `fopen`, it has perhaps (at most) two choices: a. call the "original" one - that's OK, b. call the one from my library - that's OK too, before that can happen, my `init` has to be called. So in both cases everything should be OK.  I am sorry, but I am reading your comments and I understand what you are saying, but I don't think you are reading my train of thought (as dumb as it may be).

Comment: I see... I don't think that  this corner case is defined in any specification. If you think this behavior is wrong you can report a bug to glibc team. IMHO `glibc` developers will answer you that since behavior is not specified, libraries shouldn't rely on it (`glibc` is not the only `libc` in the world). In add, behavior you ask is difficult to implement and it is better to _Keep It Simple Stupid_.

Comment: OK thank you, and in the light of this problem, I will switch to your method, much better than using init as I was doing.