# What is `constinit` in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, constinit

`constinit` is a new [keyword](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.key) and [specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constinit) in C++20 which was proposed in [P1143](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1143r2.html).

The following example is provided in the standard:

```
const char * g() { return "dynamic initialization"; }
constexpr const char * f(bool p) { return p ? "constant initializer" : g(); }
constinit const char * c = f(true);     // OK
constinit const char * d = f(false);    // ill-formed
```

A few questions come to mind:

- What does `constinit` mean? Why was it introduced? In which cases should we use it?
- Does it make a variable immutable? Does it imply `const` or `constexpr`?
- Can a variable be both `const` and `constinit`? What about `constexpr` and `constinit`?
- To which variables can the specifier be applied? Why cannot we apply it to non-`static`, non-`thread_local` variables?
- Does it have any performance advantages?

<sub>*This question is intended to be used as a reference for upcoming questions about `constinit` in general.*</sub>

Answer (score 104, accepted):

> - What does `constinit` mean? Why was it introduced? In which cases should we use it?

Initializing a variable with [*static storage duration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_storage_duration) might result in two outcomes¹:

1. The variable is initialized at compile-time ([*constant-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization));
2. The variable is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration.

Case (2) is problematic because it can lead to the [*static initialization order fiasco*](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order), which is a source of dangerous bugs related to global objects.

The `constinit` keyword can only be applied on variables with *static storage duration*. If the decorated variable is not initialized at compile-time, the program is ill-formed (i.e. does not compile).

Using `constinit` ensures that the variable is initialized at compile-time, and that the *static initialization order fiasco* cannot take place.

---

> - Does it make a variable immutable? Does it imply `const` or `constexpr`?

No and no.

However, `constexpr` does imply `constinit`.

---

> - Can a variable be both `const` and `constinit`? What about `constexpr` and `constinit`?

It can be both  `const` and `constinit`. It cannot be both `constexpr` and `constinit`. From the wording:

> > At most one of the `constexpr`, `consteval`, and `constinit` keywords shall appear in a decl-specifier-seq.

`constexpr` is not equivalent to `const constinit`, as the former mandates *constant destruction*, while the latter doesn't.

---

> - To which variables can the specifier be applied? Why cannot we apply it to non-`static`, non-`thread_local` variables?

It can only be applied to variables with static or thread storage duration. It does not make sense to apply it to other variables, as `constinit` is all about static initialization.

---

> - Does it have any performance advantages?

No. However, a collateral benefit of initializing a variable at compile-time is that it doesn't take instructions to initialize during program execution. `constinit` helps developers ensure that is the case without having to guess or check the generated assembly.

---

¹: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables

Comment: *"cannot be both `constexpr` and `constinit`"* Is that because `constexpr` effectively implies `constinit`?

Comment: "`constexpr` does imply `constinit`" - I'd not say so, since `constexpr` might be applied to local variables, while `constinit` cannot.

Comment: "It can be both const and constinit". Is that effectively the same as constexpr? Also can you clarify why it does not make sense to apply constinit to local variables?

Comment: @pooya13: 1. no, `constexpr` also mandates constant destruction. 2. it doesn't make sense because non-`static` local variables can't be initialized at compile-time.

Comment: @Mikhail: But it is fair to say that it implies `constinit` for a non-local variable (and always implies `const` and a bit more).

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to talk about *all* dynamic initialization as happening when “control passes through its declaration”; that’s only for local statics.

Comment: "constexpr mandates *constant destruction*". Can you just hint what does this means?

Comment: @meda, probably that the type needs a `constexpr` destructor. (Before C++20, the destructor had to be trivial, i.e. `= default`.)

Answer (score 4):

**MAIN PROBLEM**:

An object is considered to be initialized only when the control passes through its declaration or its definition; otherwise (i.e the control jump into a function defined in the source file in which this object is declared or defined, it doesn't see it at all) any access to this uninitialized object is undefined behavior.

Moreover, the order of initializing static-duration objects defined into multiple translation units is also undefined. You don't have a way in code to request the compiler to initialize a static object before or after another one because one object is depending on the other. Actually you cannot do this. It's up to the compiler to decide which object should be initialized first; in particular this actually depends on the order of compiling each source file.

**Example - *Segmentation fault***

```
// main.cpp
#include "src1.h"
A a{ 10 };      // declaring an object of class A with static duration.
int main() {}

// src1.cpp
#include "src1.h"
#include "src2.h"
B b{ 20 };      // declaring an object of class B with static duration.
A::A(int x): m_x(x) { b.f(); }

//src2.cpp
#include "src2.h"
int B::f() { return m_x; }
B::B(int x):  m_x(x) { }

//src1.h
struct A { 
    private: int m_x;
    public: A(int); 
};

//src2.h
struct B { 
    private: int m_x;
    public: B(int); int f(); 
};

g++ main.cpp src1.cpp src2.cpp // OK: main.cpp should be compiled first
g++ main.cpp src2.cpp src1.cpp // OK: main.cpp should be compiled first
g++ any_other_order // sigfault
```

**WORKAROUND:**

[constinit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constinit) gets introduced in C++20

Comment: It actually depends on the order the object files are linked. See [Static variables initialisation order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/211237/12447766).

Comment: Could you explain *why* main.cpp must be compiled first? It makes no sense to me.