# What's the real difference between "constinit" and "constexpr"?

Tags: c++, constexpr, semantics, c++20, constinit

```
constexpr int f() { return 0; }
int g() { return 0; }

constexpr auto c1 = f(); // OK
constinit auto c2 = f(); // OK

constexpr auto d1 = g(); // ill-formed
constinit auto d2 = g(); // ill-formed

int main() {}
```

As illustrated in the code above, I cannot find any difference between `constinit` and `constexpr`.

**What's the real difference between `constinit` and `constexpr`?**

---

Update:

The related [What is `constinit` in C++20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57845131/what-is-constinit-in-c20) doesn't clearly state the difference between `constinit` and `constexpr`.

Comment: @E_net4thedupefinder, the answer in your link doesn't clearly state the difference between `constinit` and `constexpr`.

Comment: Yes, it does. The very first answer goes into explicit detail about what `constexpr` entails and how `constinit` does not imply most of those things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `constinit` variable is constant initialized, but it is not usable in a constant expression, nor even automatically constant. Your `main` can legally contain this line

```
c2 = 2;
```

Yup, modification is possible after initialization.

Comment: From cppreference: *"`constexpr` mandates that the object must have static initialization and **constant destruction** and makes the object const-qualified, however, `constinit` does not mandate **constant destruction** and `const`-qualification."* Just for me, can you just hint me what does this **constant destruction** means;  just how `constexpr` mandates this and `constinit` is not.

Comment: @AccessDenied - I can't. As far as I can tell this is something that appears only on cppreference, and so may very well be cooked up by whomever edited that entry.