# How can I initialize a mutable variable at compile time?

Tags: c++

I can initialize a variable at compile time using `constexpr`, but this makes the variable immutable (i.e. `const`).

I want a variable that is guaranteed to be initialized at compile time, but that I can still mutate/modify at run-time.

Comment: maybe clarify, what code would you like to write but cannot?

Comment: Worth noting, although `constinit` exists in C++20, it can only be applied to static and thread-local objects. Its main purpose is to prevent the static initialization order fiasco, not to provide a "compile-time constant but mutable" variable. The latter concept is not that useful, but if you really need it, it can be emulated by making a non-`const` copy of a `constexpr` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i think there should be non const and compile time evaluated variable.

Take a look at [C++20's `constinit`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57845131/9305398).