# Changes/Diffenece between C++20 and C++17 particularly "constinit" keyword

Tags: c++, c++20

The new version of C++ .i.e. C++20 has many changes, removals, and new features. I am trying to understand the keyword "constinit". Please can anyone explain it clearly?

I found this phrase somewhere on the internet about constinit "A variable is constant-initialized by constinit but, it is still mutable?" I am not able to get this.

Comment: As for the new features of C++20 https://github.com/AnthonyCalandra/modern-cpp-features and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20

Comment: As for `constinit`, we have a [question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57845131/8586227).

Comment: Thanks @DavisHerring for the link to original question

Comment: I will make sure to search more exhaustive for questions to avoid duplication

Comment: is there a way to search more exhaustive? No matter how hard you search, always a duplicate question pops up.

Comment: there should be some sort of effective indexing to find relevant questions and avoid duplication.