# In which practical case is "const constinit" useful?

Tags: c++, constants, c++20, constinit

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57845131/what-is-constinit-in-c20) question from [@Vittorio Romeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598696/vittorio-romeo) explains `constinit` very well. In his answer, the following is mentioned:

> `constexpr` is not equivalent to `const constinit`, as the former mandates *constant destruction*, while the latter doesn't.

Although pretty clear, I fail to see any practical use of this. In which case would `const constinit` be used, but `constexpr` could not. In any case that I can think of, for any type `T` that can be `constinit` and cannot be changed during runtime via `const`, *constant destruction* should be a trivial restriction to add. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you have a type you cannot change and the destructor is not constexpr? I had a similar case the other day, fortunately I was in control of the destructor's code and could change it.

Comment: @bitmask So the only case where this could be useful is if you can't change the type `T`?

Comment: I mean, there could be a legitimate reason why the dtor is non-constexpr but the ctor is. I just cannot think of one.

Comment: Maybe some constructors are constexpr, but other function/ctors cannot be (and are allocating resources), and the destructor must then be non-constexpr ?

Comment: @Brotcrunsher: Does there need to be a use case? Why add language to the standard to stop people from using a particular combination of qualifiers, just because some other qualifier might be better for them?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas For the same reason why the `register` keyword was removed (still reserved though). For something to be a part of a language, I guess it should have some kind of use - this is obviously just my opinion though. If this would not be the case, then why wasn't the `fizzbuzz` keyword introduced long ago, which does absolutely nothing but can be placed where ever you want?

Comment: @Brotcrunsher: No, `register` was *never* useful. `const` is useful. `constinit` is useful. And they're not the same *kind* of qualifier, so they're not automatically mutually exclusive. So you'd have to invent a reason to forbid their use *together*.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dependency on external code that you cannot change for whatever reason, and it looks like this

```
struct A {
  ~A() {}
};
```

This will mean that `A` is not a literal type because it doesn't have a `constexpr` destructor (most likely an oversight). It could however be constructed at compile time and therefore be a `constinit`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible practical case:

```
struct AtExit
{
    ~AtExit() { std::cout << "End"; }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ce0c84228d7b345)

(More useful by templating the class with functor).